# How do I wait for a for loop to finish in batch before continuing?

Tags: batch-file

I currently have a batch script that I'm using to copy one large zip file from a network folder to multiple machines on the network. I need to do these copies in parallel so I've got a for loop that runs through addresses and runs start robocopy. Here's what I've got

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (IPlist.txt) do (

    start robocopy "\\networkfolder" \\%%A
)
```

The problem is that I need to execute an extract on all the machines I just copied to but I need to wait until the robocopies have finished. I can't use start /wait in the for loop since that destroys the parallel copy. Is there a way I can force the script to wait until all the robocopies have finished? or maybe an alternate solution?

FYI: I cannot extract on the network folder first since the zip is a lot of little files and severely slows the transfer rate. It needs to be one big file when copying over the network.

Comment: Maybe you can use the `tasklist` command in a loop to check whether there are any robocopy processes still running, and if so, sleep for a while and try again?

Answer (score 2):

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set number=0
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (IPlist.txt) do (
    set /A number+=1
    echo Flag > roboRunning.!number!
    start robocopy "\\networkfolder" \\%%A ^& del roboRunning.!number!
)

:wait
if exist roboRunning.* goto wait

echo All robocopy processes have finished here
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code I had lying around (syntax for inside a batch file):

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set robocopycount=0

:loop
for /F "usebackq" %%e IN (`tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq robocopy.exe"`) do if %%e==robocopy.exe set /A robocopycount=!robocopycount!+1

if %robocopycount% GEQ 1 goto continue
rem goto loop

:continue
```

This actually counts the number of executables running at once but it could easily be adapted to just check for existence. (In the case of this code it was checking to ensure that a certain number were running.)

Answer (score 0):

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET num=0
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A in (IPlist.txt) do (
    SET /A num+=1
    ECHO Flag > RoboRunNum.!num!
    START robocopy "\\networkfolder" \\%%A ^& del RoboRunNum.!num!
)

:Check
if exist RoboRunNum.* GOTO CHECK

echo Robocopy Processes fave Finished
```